# Exception message not being shown if json_encode is applied to the output

Tags: php, exception, json

Here's the code:

```
try{
//The exception is thrown.
throw new Exception('Parâmetros de consulta inválidos');

// and in the catch block it's caught successfully:
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage(); //This prints the message correctly.

    $output = json_encode(array('msg'=>$e->getMessage()));
    echo $output; //But this fails...displays {"msg":null}

}
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Seems to work http://codepad.org/6hvr4CLP

Comment: @jprofitt I just love when it works everywhere but on my machine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the character â and á. Infact, if you replace them with a simple a, you'll get the right message.

Replace this line:

```
array('msg'=>$e->getMessage())
```

with this:

```
array('msg'=>utf8_encode($e->getMessage()))
```

You have to do this change because the json_encode works with ut8 as you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: @Jorge Glad to help you. Anyway I've update my answer so you can also echo your special chars. ;)

Comment: I always have issues with the encoding, once i managed to print chinese characters, don't ask me how because i don't know. (Was using Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a PHP version >= 5.4.0, you should call to the json_encode function with the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php