# PHP Try Catch with custom error handler always returns empty exception

Tags: php, exception, null, try-catch

I'm trying to follow [Can I try/catch a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728) and treat all warnings as exceptions. I can get the error details in the custom error handler but the ErrorException I get in my catch block is always empty.

```
private function SetCustomExceptionHandler() {
        set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext) {
            log_message('error', '$errno ' . $errno);
            log_message('error', '$errstr ' . $errstr);
            log_message('error', '$errfile ' . $errfile);
            log_message('error', '$errline ' . $errline);
            log_message('error', '$errcontext ' . json_encode($errcontext));

            throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
        });
    }

$this->SetCustomExceptionHandler();
            try {
                //LDAP query that returns: ldap_search(): Partial search results returned: Sizelimit exceeded
            }
            catch (ErrorException $e) {

                log_message('error', json_encode($e));
            }
```

Comment: Maybe there's no JSON encoding for exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered here: [Exception message not being shown if json_encode is applied to the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836813/exception-message-not-being-shown-if-json-encode-is-applied-to-the-output)

In my code, all I had to do was the following:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    $data['exception'] = $e->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

This was enough to get my exception data to come through my JSON array.